# iframe disappears for no apparent reason after dynamically creating it

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, google-chrome-extension, jquery-autocomplete

This is quite difficult to explain, but I've never experienced something like this before. I've also created a GIF to display what the issue looks like.

The first time I open my chrome extension and make a search the iframe works perfectly fine. The second time I open my chrome extension and make a search the iframe disappears (see GIF).

[image]

As you can see the iframe suddenly disappears for no apparent reason, and if I right click and go into `inspect element` and edit even the most unrelated item then all of a sudden the iframe reappears.

Is there a simple solution I can try? As I said when I toggle any piece of code in the `inspect element` view in chrome it reappears.

Here is the code for searching: (I'm using jquery Autocomplete for the search)

```
$('#searchBox').autocomplete({
lookup: footballers,
lookupLimit: 5,
minChars: 3,
onSelect: function (suggestion) {
    $("#searchBox").blur();     
    $('.fullcard').css('display', 'block');
    $('.fullcard').append('<i id="closeCard" class="material-icons">close</i><iframe src="https://www.example.com/'+suggestion.data+'"></iframe>');
},
lookupFilter: _autocompleteLookup,
formatResult: _autocompleteFormatResult, 
});
```

Any thoughts/ideas? Highly appreciate it.

Comment: Any chance your iframe is getting reloaded unintentionally (like after a form submit)?

Comment: It might be because of you are loading to another page.

Comment: @jfriend00 but that wouldn't explain why it loads the first time, but not the second...

Comment: Maybe, maybe not (depends upon your code), but it is a very common mistake that causes a page to flash and then reload so I'd suggest you check to see if this is happening.  You haven't disclosed enough of the situation for us to see whether this could be happening so all I can do is ask you to check.  It's simple enough to see in the network tab of the Chrome debugger if a page reload is happening due to a form submit.

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm not actually using a form I simply have a textbox and `jquery-autocomplete` takes care of the rest. I also checked the chrome debugger and it doesn't seem like a reload is happening.

Comment: I've had a remotely similar problem due to an already [fixed bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=422143) in Chrome 37-40, so the workaround was to toggle any visible element's `style.webkitTransform` between `""` and `"scale(1)"`.

Comment: @wOxxOm Could you explain the workaround a little more?

Comment: Well, I was googling back then and found some page (maybe [this](http://www.eccesignum.org/blog/solving-display-refreshredrawrepaint-issues-in-webkit-browsers)) with the workaround.

Comment: @wOxxOm Wow. The `scale` actually worked for me! I can't believe I've spent countless hours trying to fix this and it was a webkit bug. If you set your reply as the answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: @Katie, ok, it's strange though, I thought the bug is fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting [John Winkelman's post](http://www.eccesignum.org/blog/solving-display-refreshredrawrepaint-issues-in-webkit-browsers):

> This is a Known Issue for Webkit browsers (Chrome, Safari). Sometimes, when updating an inline element or style, the browser does not redraw/repaint the screen until a block-level change happens in the DOM. This bug  most often occurs when there is a lot going on in the page [...]

- Fix 1:

  ```
  document.getElementById('myElement').style.webkitTransform = 'scale(1)';
  ```
- Fix 2 in case the element isn't repainted when scrolling the page:

  ```
  document.addEventListener("scroll", function(event) {
      var style = document.getElementById("name").style;
      style.webkitTransform = style.webkitTransform ? "" : "scale(1)";
  });
  ```

  This case was recently [fixed](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=422143) in Chrome/Chromium.

Comment: You just saved my life with this answer... I was trying to fix this problem for days now. If you could only see how many Google searches I've done on this. You don't know true desperation until you get to page 5+ of your Google search! Thanks a lot!