# Iframe contents showing up blank

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm trying to show a webpage with a bootstrap carousel in an iframe on my program but it is showing up blank. If I inspect, all the elements are there, and I'm able to click on the buttons that I know are on the page that's supposed to show in the iframe, but the iframe remains blank. If I reload the page a bunch of times, sometimes it shows up properly. I'm loading boostrap through cdns in the head of the iframe page and interestingly, when I comment-out the bootstrap.min.css link, the carousel obviously breaks, but the page shows up within the iframe.

This is not an X-frames issue and doesn't seem to be a [webkit issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31500413/8862954).

Here's the head of my (.jade) page that contains the carousel (that is the page supposed to be within the iframe). The carousel itself is a basic [bootstrap carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/).

```
block meta_head
meta(name='robots', content='noindex')

//Latest compiled and minified CSS
link(rel='stylesheet', href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css')
//jQuery library
script(src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js')
//Latest compiled JavaScript
script(src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js')
link(rel='stylesheet', href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons')
link(rel='stylesheet', href='https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css')
```

The html containing the iframe:

```
<div id="my-element-container">
    <div id="my-element">
        <div id="iframe-container">
            <iframe id="my-iframe" src="https://www.mywebsite.com/myPageWithCarousel/" scrolling="no"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be HUGELY appreciated.

Comment: Any warnings or errors in the F12 developer tools console?

Comment: No errors or warnings @DaveS